# Passport not stamped French carte de sejour

Tags: visas, france, passport-stamps

I am an Egyptian national who lived as a student in France and when I flew out in 2008, my carte de sejour had expired some 3 months prior. At the airport, the official remarked upon it but I apologised and explained my renewal appointment was for much later but I was leaving France. He didn't say anything further, there was no fine or paperwork or any overstay stamp and he let me go. However, there was no exit stamp on the passport.

Between then and now, I've received many long and short-term UK, US, and German visas and I have a new passport too since the past few years with other visas (Australia, Brazil, Canada). I also got a French short-term Schengen visa for a business conference a few years ago. Now, I have to apply for a French long term visa (VLS-TS) but I am wondering if my old French stay will cause problem since I have to mention if I ever stayed in France for more than 3 months in the visa form and will probably have to provide photocopy of the old French student visa (don't have the copy of the carte de sejour).

The French official didn't mark any exit stamp on my passport when I left with my carte de sejour in 2008, will that be an issue? Will the French think that their border guard didn't stamp my exit, so that means there was a problem? I've noticed that Germany never stamped me in or out whenever I left the EU with my temporary residence card (I am not an EU citizen family member).

Comment: Passports are not supposed to be stamped for holders of a residence permit. Schengen Border Code, Article 11 (3)(g).

Comment: @MarkJohnson They are supposed to be stamped systematically for all third country nationals with a residence permit or long term visa, except those who were granted residence permit as families of EU citizens. Although in practice, many countries do not stamp any residence permit holders since it's useless.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Article 11(3)(g) concerns only "a residence card provided for in Directive 2004/38/EC," which does not include most residence permits such as student permits.

Comment: @phoog Does this mean that he ought to have stamped my passport and it's worrisome that he didn't? Was it a way to indicate something about my carte de séjour? My sister lives in Finland and when she moved there on a 3-month residence card (internship), she wasn't stamped in either.

Comment: @guest38721 he ought to have stamped your passport, but it's not particularly worrisome that he didn't.